# How to predefined AWS security group id using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli

This script works fine for creating EC2 instances:

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "ACCESS_KEY"
  secret_key = "SECRET-KEY"
  region     = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count = 3
  ami           = "ami-001as38b07206d4ceaf"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name   = "labkey"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ "sg-341233f1856" ]
}
```

Now I am trying to create a security group. The script works fine however I cannot find out how to predefined the "vpc_security_group_ids" when creating the security group

```
resource "aws_security_group" "Testlab_VPC_Security_Group" {
  vpc_id       = aws_vpc.Testlab_VPC.id
  name         = "Testlab VPC Security Group"
  description  = "Testlab VPC Security Group"
  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = var.ingressCIDRblock
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
  }
  ingress {
    cidr_blocks = var.ingressCIDRblock
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
  }
  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
tags = {
   Name = "Testlab VPC Security Group"
   Description = "Testlab VPC Security Group"
}
}
```

I would like to be able to combine both of these scripts.

Is there another way to add the security using terraform that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  count = 3
  ami           = "ami-001as38b07206d4ceaf"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name   = "labkey"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ aws_security_group.Testlab_VPC_Security_Group.id ]
}
```

Because this expression refers to the security group, Terraform can infer automatically that the security group must be created first.